# Python Как в input вставить свое значение автоматически

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon

У меня есть следующий код:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.sessions import StringSession

number=77777369140
api_id=2229909
api_hash="54cccd7d67d89a8473e6f9ea95bf3454"

with TelegramClient(StringSession(), api_id, api_hash) as client:
    print(client.session.save())
```

После его запуска в командной строке выводит:

```
Please enter your phone (or bot token): _
```

Естественно все останавливается. Как автоматически вставить туда number и нажать enter
PS Сам input спрятан в дебрях telethon/client/auth.py

Comment: еще раз перечитайте свой вопрос и уточните его более связно пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

По определению - input() это функция предназначенная для ввода данных в программу. Точка.

Хотите получать данные как-то по другому - ковыряйте "дебри" и переделывайте получение данных. Способы переделки могут быть различными. От брутального удаления этого оператора и явного константного задания вашей переменной, до получения данных из заранее созданного файла или чтение из какой-нибудь глобальной переменной. Не хотите - вводите его так, как того требует скрипт, который вы хотите использовать.

Comment: Я надеялся, может есть фишка какая. Уже полез в дебри.

Comment: Рад, что вы все правильно поняли из моего ответа.

Comment: Рад, что вы рады! 